# ggmap and get_stamenmap return an error when plotting a region

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

I have been using package `ggmaps` in `Rstudio` for several months for spatial distribution plots.

The basic line of code employed for plotting a `terrain-background` map is as follows:

```
### Load packages ####
library(tidyverse); library(googlesheets4); library(openintro)
library(maps); library(ggmap); library(ggthemes); library(Cairo)

#### Set bounding box of Africa ####
bbox2 <- c(left = -18.63,
           right = 52.03,
           bottom = -35.32,
           top = 38.96)

Africa <- get_stamenmap(
  bbox = bbox2,
  maptype = c("terrain-background"),
  zoom = 7)
```

Since this morning, the following error is returned:

```
Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

As I mentioned, these lines of code have been working perfectly in the past months (plotted the same region on 2023/10/02). I have also tried previous regions which were plotted before (for example Europe) and the same error is returned.

I have tried several solutions: restarting the R session, updating R and RStudio, re-installing ggmpas and associated packages....Non of them have worked

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from `ggmap:::stitch` which tries to bind together map tiles after they have been downloaded. This appears to be because the individual tiles vary in dimension, even with a fixed zoom, which makes binding them together problematic. This is a change in the package behaviour which is obviously related to a server-side change and was [reported as an issue](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/353) on the package's github page yesterday. Hopefully this should be resolved quite quickly.

Answer (score 5):

This "[Migration Guide for Stamen Map Tile Users](https://docs.stadiamaps.com/guides/migrating-from-stamen-map-tiles/#ggmap)" by *Stadia Maps, Inc.* looks promising.

Here in short the main steps for `ggmap` (for other libraries see link above):

> 1. [Create a Stadia Maps account](https://stadiamaps.com/stamen/onboarding/create-account). The onboarding flow will walk you through setting up domain authentication or an API key.
> 2. There is a open pull request to ggmap, version 4.0.0 is expected to fully support the changes, but until then one can install the
>    Stadia Maps fork of ggmap:
>
> ```r
> remove.packages("ggmap")
> devtools::install_github("stadiamaps/ggmap")
> ```
>
> 3. You can now use either `get_stadiamap` (which replaces the `get_stamenmap` function) or `qmplot` as before. Note that the `maptype` parameter for Stamen styles match our style names and
>    include a `stamen_` prefix. Here is a minimal example that shows a map of the US using get_stadiamap. Make sure to register an account to get an API key. You can optionally persist the key by passing `write = TRUE` to `register_stadiamaps`.
>
> ```r
> library("ggmap") 
> register_stadiamaps("YOUR-API-KEY-HERE") 
> us <- c(left = -125, bottom = 25.75, right = -67, top = 49)
> get_stadiamap(us, zoom = 5, maptype = "stamen_toner") %>% ggmap()
> ```

Comment: please note the mismatched double-quote character in the install_github() call above.  
I was unable to edit the answer myself (edit queue full)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, and I resolved it by reducing the map's zoom level until I found the highest one that didn't result in an error.

```
  for(i in seq(zoom, 1)){
    print(zoom)
    stamenbck <- tryCatch(ggmap::get_stamenmap(bbox, 
                                               zoom = zoom,
                                               maptype = "terrain"), error = function(e) NULL)
    zoom <- zoom - 1
    if (!is.null(stamenbck)) {
      print(zoom)
      break
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried this solution with a sequence from 15 to 1. Got errors for all the explored zoom's.
Thank you very much. Despite not solving the issue, it is a very good approach to solve similar issues.